# Load parts of App.Config from another file

Tags: c#, configuration, app-config

I like to split my `app.config` into a user specific part and an application specific part. Is it possible to store a part of the `app.config` in another file?

I already tried this:

```
<!DOCTYPE cruisecontrol [<!ENTITY email SYSTEM "email.config">]  >
```

but this does not load.

Is there another possiblity without changing the application itself?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use the `configSource` attribute to tell the framework to load a particular section from another file.

For example, if you had a config file with a section like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDatabase" connectionString="...etc..." />
</connectionStrings>
```

You could replace it with:

```
  <connectionStrings configSource="ConnectionStrings.config" />
```

...and create a file `ConnectionStrings.config` with the contents of the original section (including the `<connectionStrings>` node - exactly the same as my first code section above).

Comment: This is so great! I have been looking for a way to do this for so long, and it was right in front of me the entire time.

Comment: The problem is that this seems to only include connection strings, but does not help when you try to include configuration sections from other files.

Comment: @Kjellski I can assure you `configSource` works for all elements. Suggest you read up on how it works: http://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/archive/2007/04/26/using-configsource-to-split-configuration-files.aspx

Comment: @JonGrant You're absolutely right, but the most important thing to notice, is that you need the part `<section name="foo" type="..">` of the `<configSections>` and then, are able to replace the `<foo>...</foo>` part with `<foo configSource="foo.config">`. But you're not able to place that attribute in the `<configSections>` part of the `[web|app].config`.

Comment: if you use "file=" instead of "configSource=